# get textfile from internal storage

Tags: android

my app writes a text file to the internal memory (sd card not available).
I want to bring this to the laptop.
My file explorer shows the internal memory but not the file it is
only a few directories can be seen, but they do not contain the text file.
I am not allowed to write in the directories (illegal argument-exception).
In the enclosed code I once wrote a text file and read it again.
My question: how can I get the text file onto the laptop?

```
  void example() {
    String me;
    try {
      FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("filenamew.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String str = "test data: xyz";
      fOut.write(str.getBytes());
      fOut.close();
      FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("filenamew.txt");
      int l = 32;
      int c;
      int le = 0;
      String temp = "";
      while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) {
        if (++le > l)
          break;
        temp = temp + (char) c;
      }
      fin.close();
      File verz = getFilesDir(); //data/user/0/de.wicki.pdftextapplication/files
      String vp=verz.getAbsolutePath(); //data/user/0/de.wicki.pdftextapplication/files
      File[] dateien = verz.listFiles();
      String q="";
      for(int i=0;i< dateien.length;i++ ){
        String name=dateien[i].getName();
        String laenge=""+dateien[i].length();
        q=q+"|"+name+":"+laenge;
      }
      q=q+" ";
  } catch(Exception e) {
      me=e.getMessage();
  }
   me="Ende" ;
}
```

Comment: `My file explorer ` ? Which one? And where is it running? You save to your apps internal private directory where File explorers/managers have no acces. The Device File Explorer of Android Studio has.

Comment: `:how can I get the text file onto the laptop?` You mean that you connected your Android device with a USB cable with your laptop? Well you will not see that private file then.

Comment: - file explorer from Windows, smartphone is connected with usb

Comment: Well then it is time you update the subject of your post and the text of it.

Comment: The Windos fileexplorer and that of the smartphone both do not display the text file in the internal storage.
My example code is just supposed to prove that the text file exists.
I would like to know how to get the text file to the laptop.

Comment: Repeat: `You save to your apps internal private directory where File explorers/managers have no acces.` And you did update nothing.

Comment: Where can I save the text file so that the file explorer can display it?
If I specify a directory (example: /Documents/filenamew.txt) the error
"illegal argument-exception" is displayed.

Comment: In the Documents directory would be ok. All depends on Android version if used device.